# How to test with buster remote fetching file function, which works but works with callback

Tags: javascript, testing, buster.js

How to test function which fetch file from remote server with Buster ?
I wrote test like

```
buster.testCase("Remote fetch file", {
    "test it": function () {
        assert(true);
    },

    "remote fetch file" : function (){
        remoteFileFetchingFunction(credentials, 'whoami', function (err, result) {
            assert.equals(result, 'John');
        });
    }

});
```

But always get error like `Failure: No assertions!`

Answer (score 1):

You have to make an asynchronous test do to this. To tag a test as asynchronous, you need to make the test function take one argument. By convention, this argument should be called `done`. Call the argument to tell buster the test has finished running. That's all there is to it :)

```
"my test": function (done) {
    doAsyncThing(function (arg) {
        assert.equals(arg, 123);
        done();
    });
}

// Alternative syntax
"my test": function (done) {
    doAsyncThing(done(function (arg) {
        assert.equals(arg, 123);
    }));
}
```

The advantage of using the alternative syntax is that if your callback function throws an error, "done" will still be called.